# Infinitely many residues mod p

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have a question.

Let $a$ and $b$ be given fixed positive integers and let's denote the the $i^\text{th}$ prime number by $p_i$  .

Prove that if

$$a \overset{p_i}{\equiv} x_i \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\text{and}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
b \overset{p_i}{\equiv} y_i 
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\text{and}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
x_i>=y_i $$ for every i.

Then a=b.

Comment: a,b are fixed as far as n

Comment: Is the integer $n$ fixed?

Comment: Yes. But we do not want x_i+y_i=n for every i but for infinetely many i's

Comment: Is the statement true?

Comment: Do you mean $n$ can varies, Or it must be fixed?

Comment: It must be fixed...

Comment: For instance: x_1=y_1+5 an

Comment: We want infinetely many residues mod 2 or mod 3 or mod 17... that differ by n

Comment: I can't understand what do you say! What do you mean by term "differ by $n$"?

Comment: x_20=y_20+5,      x_42=y_42+5 ...

Comment: Is the statement now clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remark**: Every integer has only finitly many prime divisors.

---

---

**Soppose on contrary** that there exists such an integer $n$,

now notice that, for infinitely many primes $p_i$:

$$p_i \mid (a-x_i) 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\text{and}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
p_i \mid (b-y_i) 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\text{and}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
x_i-y_i=n. 
$$

So we must have:

$$p_i \mid \Big( (a-x_i)-(b-y_i) \Big) 
\ \ \ \ 
\Longrightarrow 
\ \ \ \ 
p_i \mid \Big( (a-b)-(x_i-y_i) \Big) 
\ \ \ \ 
\Longrightarrow 
\ \ \ \ 
p_i \mid \Big( (a-b)-n \Big) . 
$$

---

This means that the integer $a-b-n$ infinitely many prime divisors $p_i$, which is an obvious **contradiction**.

Comment: Can we know prove tg

Comment: That if x_i>=y_i for all i then a=b!

Comment: a=b not b factorial

Comment: @Harris P. Could you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: Of course! We have the same statement and x_i >=y_i for every i. There is no more the statement that x_i=y_i+n

Comment: So, for every i the residue of a mod p_i is bigger than the residue of b mod p_i . Prove that a=b.

Comment: I can't understand, could you explain again?

Comment: Edited! I think it is very clear

Comment: Any Ideas for the problem?